# Does the element-wise ordering of three vectors also hold for their sums?

Tags: linear-algebra, order-theory

Consider the case of vectors $l, x, u \in \mathbb{R}^{p+}$ such that for each element of the vectors it holds that $l \le x \le u.$

This ordering holds for example for $l= [1,2,3]^T$, $x=[4,5,6]^T$, $u=[7,8,9]^T$, because $1<4<7, \ 2<5<8, \ 3<6<9$.

I am interested whether this ordering also holds after applying the function $f$ on the vectors, in particular the summation of all elements: $f(y)=e^Ty$, where $e$ the unit vector.

In the example we have $6<15<24$, so the order holds after applying $f$.

Is this problem known under a particular name and does it have a general answer? Note again we are in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, but I am not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Trivial problem.

Comment: @WilliamElliot could you explan why? I think intuitively its true but I am not sure where to start for a proof.

Comment: Exercise.  Assume a < b, u < v.  Prove a + u < b + v.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Okay. So $a-b<0$, $v-u>0$ thus $a-b < v-u$. So you are saying that this holds for $p$ elements follows by inducation?

Comment: I did not say a - b < v - u.